# Create a glance image can not retrieve token

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I am trying to create a windows based image on Openstack using glance. I get an error about authentication plugin, I am able to retrieve a token using keystone (token-get), heres is my error :

```
root@Machine:~# glance --os-username USER --os-password PASS --os-project-domain-name windows --os-project-name windows --os-auth-url http://Controller:35357/v2.0   image-create --name="win8"   --property vm_mode=HVM  --is-public=true  --container-format=ovf --disk-format=vhd < tarred.tgz
```

> An auth plugin is required to fetch a token

Answer (score 0):

TO avoid this problem add OpenStack environment variables:

```
source admin-openrc.sh
```